# Expected value formula? Unsure.

Tags: probability

[image]I must stress that this is an assignment, so I don't want an answer to the question. However, I'm simply stuck on part (iv). I gave an expression for (iii), no problem. However, I'm unsure exactly what is being asked for me for (iv). The expected value of Y? But if Y is, say, 3, then the probability for that is 1/8. Plugging 1/8 into that equation gives me a result of 7 and 1/7. I'm very unsure here and would love some guidance so I can tackle this myself.

Comment: What is $P(Y = k)$ that you found? Notice that $E(Y) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty k P(Y = k),$ so if you found $P(Y = k),$ you can find (iv).

Comment: Your formula is almost correct, if $Y = k,$ there is no need to sum over $k.$

Comment: $p$ i assume is the probability of getting heads. It should be a constant

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're assuming a fair dice $(p = 0.5)$ and confusing P with p itself

$P(Y = 3)$ is a function of $p$ (the probability of getting heads in a single toss). It is equal to 1/8 as you say, but only if p is equal to 0.5 (which, i don't know if it's resolved in points i) and ii) but it doesn't matter if p was known before hand since you're now asked to solve for P *in terms of p*)

Then you're apparently using that 1/8 again, evaluating $E(Y)$ with $p = 1/8$ to get $50/7$, that's just nonsense: Wasn't p = 0.5 already?

Comment: $p$ is a constant itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for $P(Y = k)$ was almost correct. The correct version is
$$
P(Y = k) = p(1-p)^k + (1-p)p^k.
$$
(This follows because you either have a run of $k$ of one type or the other, and the $k+1$ throw has to break the run.) Then
$$
E(Y) = \sum k P(Y = k) = \sum k \big( p(1-p)^k + (1-p)p^k \big) = \ldots = \dfrac{1-2p+2p^2}{p(1-p)}.
$$

Comment: If you don't know how to evaluate functions, then you shouldn't be doing probability!